# Select spinner by id instead of position

Tags: java, android, spinner, android-spinner

How to select spinner by ID, Spinner is populated from DB, and in edit mode I want to select saved spinner ID again. 
Is there any build in function to solve this issue?
Like we have in .net,

```
drp.SelectedValue

spCustomer.setId(tr.getVendCustID());
```

Comment: you need to create a function that have the is as input and return the position as output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my answer,

```
for (int i = 0; i < spCustomer.getCount(); i++) {
                if (Integer.parseInt(((PopulateSpinner) spCustomer.getItemAtPosition(i)).id) == tr.getVendCustID()) {
                    spCustomer.setSelection(i);
                    break;
                }
```

Comment: any simple or easy way will be appreciated